# sum of two dedekind cuts

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic

according to Dedekind cut definition in Pugh analysis book, if $ x=A|B $ and $y=C|D$ definition of two cuts addition is as following $x+y=E|F$ which E={e=a+c:$a\in A$ and $c\in C$} and F=Q\E I can understand that why E and F are nonempty and E doesn't have largest element but I can't understand why every element of E is less than F. can someone please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in E$ and $y \le x$, then $x = a + c$ for some $a \in A$ and $c \in C$, but then $y = (a + y - x) + c$ and $a + y - x \le a$, so $a + y - x \in A$, because $A\mid B$ is a cut, giving us that $y \in E$. Hence, if $F = \Bbb{Q} \setminus E$ and $f \in F$ we cannot have $f \le x$ for any $x\in E$, so we must have that $f > x$ for every $x\in E$.